# Objective C, A Question about return type of a method in a protocol

Tags: objective-c, protocols

I have Type.h file looks like

```
typedef enum MessageType{
    msgTypeOne,
    msgTypetwo,
            .
            .
            .   
}
```

And I defined a protocol and a method in the protocol is trying to return the MessageType..
It looks like this

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Type.h"

@protocol Message

- (int) getId;
- (MessageType) getType;
- (int) getSize;
- (NSData *) toBytes;
- (void) fromBytes:(NSData *)data;

@end
```

Then I am getting an error saying "No type or storage class may be specified here before protocol"

Any ideas? How I can fix this?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Is this all one file?  If not, you may need to import the file that defines your type into the file that declares your protocol.  What is that import word doing in there?  You should format your code so it is readable and correct.

Comment: I added import as well but stil getting the error. So right under the uikit import statement I added Type.h but it still doesn't work

Comment: Please paste your real enum code. That is not valid Objective-C enum syntax. You may well be typedef'ing it wrongly.

Comment: I missed a comma after each variable...

Comment: If that is all, you are typedefing your enum to nothing. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `typedef` your enum to `MessageType`. Currently you are `typedef`ing an `enum MessageType` to nothing.

Change your enum code to this, placing `MessageType` after the closing brace:

```
typedef enum {
    msgTypeOne,
    msgTypetwo,
    // ... 
} MessageType;
```

This `typedef`s an anonymous enum to the user-defined type `MessageType`. Your protocol *should* now compile correctly.

Answer (score 0):

@Chayong Lee you need to define the `protocol` at the end of the class something like this

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
interface something : NSObject
{
}

@end
@protocol some

@end
```

and if you are using that protocol in the interface then you need to do something like this

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol some;

interface something : NSObject
{
}

@end
@protocol some

@end
```

Comment: A protocol can live in its own file.

Comment: I want to declare a header file that declares the enum so that other classes might also use that. Also, I want to create a separate protocol in .h file so that other classes also might implement the protocol. So I couldn't just add everything in one file that is the main problem..